# Select records from database in specific date period

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok I have this example table:

```
+-------+--------+-----------+
| users | groups | startDate |
+-------+--------+-----------+
| Foo   | A      | 1 Aug 18  |
| Foo   | B      | 1 Jan 18  |
| Boo   | C      | 1 Jan 18  |
| Doo   | B      | 1 Jan 18  |
| Loo   | B      | 1 Sep 18  |
+-------+--------+-----------+
```

and I want to select (Group B) users with "startDate" not higher than today and also without any other records for other groups in more recent "startDate" also not higher than today, so the correct result should be:

```
+-------+--------+-----------+
| users | groups | startDate |
+-------+--------+-----------+
| Doo   | B      | 1 Jan 18  |
+-------+--------+-----------+
```

I tried the following code but didn't get what I need:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '2018-08-01'
DECLARE @GroupID varchar(1) = 'B';
WITH CurrentUsers AS (SELECT users, groups, startDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY users ORDER BY CASE WHEN startDate>@StartDate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, startDate)) ASC) AS RowNum FROM usersTable) SELECT users FROM CurrentUsers WHERE groups=@GroupID AND RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you seem to want:

```
select user
from currentusers cu
group by user
having sum(case when groups = @GroupID then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- in Group B
       max(startdate) < @StartDate;
```

EDIT:

The above is based on a misunderstanding.  You want people whose active group is today.  I think you want:

```
WITH CurrentUsers AS (
      SELECT users, groups, startDate,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY users
                              ORDER BY startDate DESC
                             ) as seqnum
      FROM usersTable
      WHERE startDate <= @StartDate
     )
SELECT users
FROM CurrentUsers
WHERE groups=@GroupID AND seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: not working, the result includes users with other group in recent date

Comment: @SherifRiad . . . This should not include any users that have any start date after `@StartDate`.

Comment: that's right, but if you noticed that user Foo has 2 Group assignments both are true in the date condition. The problem is that user Foo is now with group A starting from 1 Aug and should not be included with group B results.

Comment: I have a different issue now.. when I try to LEFT JOIN the result with the users table to get users names and so on it gives a different result. your query in my real data gives 26 records.. but after the left join it's only 14 records

Comment: @SherifRiad . . . You should ask a new question as a *new* question, with sample data and desired results.

Comment: It's not a seperate or new question.. it's just an amend to the current one, I want to understand why when I try to join another table of user data to this one the results is way less than it should be while the other table is already bigger than this one and I tried all kinds of join, left, right and inner. all the same. Can you just think it out with me please?

Comment: I can't even figure out how right, left and inner joint give same results?!